InteillJ stucks in recompiling with Grails 6.2.0 once groovy file changes
Environment
IntelliJ 2024.1.3
Grails 6.2.0
JDK openjdk-17.0.2
Previous with grails-6.1.2 everything works. When running grails-6.1.2 project in IntelliJ in debug mode IDE can auto recompile and re-run project once groovy file updates.
But after upgraded to grails-6.2.0 once groovy file updated IDE stucked in recompiling and never restarted project. You have to manully click on re-run button.
I tried to clear all caches and rebuild project but nothing helped.
Does anyone have same issue?
IDE auto re-run after re-compiling
